# Add maven repo without requiring index

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I added a repo to my gradle build and Android Studio started downloading a 904MB maven index file.

```
maven { url "http://maven.atlassian.com/content/groups/public/" }
```

I'll admit it - I have no idea why Idea needs to download the maven index. As far as I can see, all it needs is the URL so it knows where to try to fetch my dependencies from.

So I'm hoping there's a way to tell Idea to not download the index. Is there?

904MB, jeez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IDEA 2016 remote repositories are not indexed by default. Only local repository is indexed. You may force update of any repository from
settings->build, execution, deployment-> maven->repositories.
There is list of indexed repositories (with update date) and update button to force update.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/maven-repositories.html for official documentation for that feature.

In older versions, it was not possible to to skip creating that index. Repositores are indexed to enable auto-complete for editing pom files (suggest groupId, artifactId and versions).

Comment: It's for autocomplete on POM files? It's hard to think of a less meaningful way to waste 900MB. Thanks Bartosz.

Comment: Yes it is only for autocomplete for POM files. you could try deleting that index, but I think it will be recreated. I am using intellij latest 14 for a few days (with maven central dependencies) and I have just realized that maven central index was not created. I have just index for my local repo, and it is (5MB). I think that remote repositories are indexed only when intelij need to reach to remote repo (artifact not found in local repo). In android studio my maven index is 1,5GB, in intelij13 (I was using that before for a few months) my index for maven central is over 2GB.